# Is the word "savage" offensive?

Tags: offensive-language

Is it?

If it depends on context, please provide some examples of offensive and not offensive usage ;)

What I have in mind is to say something like "The Zulu were a savage people compared to e.g. the United Kingdom".

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by offensive?

Comment: Yes, the example you have in mind is very offensive.  It is likely to provoke great anger and, from the more patient, a history lesson.

Comment: I don't think [Fred Savage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Savage) finds it offensive to refer to his last name :)

Comment: Whether the British were less savage than the Zulu depends on the victim's point of view.  I'm sure there are many aboriginal people who would argue that imperialist Britain was as savage as any nation that came before it.

Comment: And, of course, you could never compare a people like *the Zulu* to a country like *the United Kingdom*. Whether the latter should be *the English*, *the British* or some other term is, mercifully, not something we need to decide now.

Comment: "Offensive" doesn't really mean what it used to.  Yes, there are words that people could consider an insult and most other people would agree were insulting.  However, offense has become a power tool.  Grievance groups have recognized that calling something offensive gives them a bargaining chip.  Well-meaning people accept the claim as fact, no matter how twisted or obtuse is the argument needed to justify its "offensiveness".  Often, the grievance group making the claim doesn't even represent the opinion of the supposedly aggrieved party.  (cont'd)

Comment: It isn't unusual for a term to be labelled as offensive when the people it is supposed to offend actually like the term.  A group that is proud of the reputation of its warriors as fierce and violent might welcome the label of "savage", even want to use it as a deterrent against other groups thinking about attacking them.  There is some logic to being careful with terms that could obviously offend.  But it is a slippery slope to deal with, and requires more than second guessing who might be offended and why, or accepting claims of offense potential at face value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When applied to animals or natural forces, it means *fierce* or *violent*. When applied to human beings, it means *cruel*, *aggressive* or *vicious*. So, it is very negative.

As a noun, a savage means “a member of a people regarded as primitive and uncivilized”, and is thus very offensive. It is now mainly a historical term.

Comment: Possible exceptions to its offensiveness may be when you describe a change in a particular person: Dr. Jekyll is composed; Mr. Hyde is savage. This would avoid any comparisons to its historical use with regards to "those savages."

Comment: Thank you. The closest equivalent of savage in my language is mildly offensive at best, and it depends on context as well, so I apologize if my example offended anyone.

Answer (score 4):

*Savage* originally meant 'wild', as *sauvage* does in Old and modern French.  It acquired two different transferred meanings when applied to human beings; as in 'savage fighters' it became 'fierce and bloodthirsty'; though this isn't always negative (whether applied to soldiers or guard-dogs) very few people would apply it to themselves, and, however apt a nineteenth-century historian might have thought your example, it can't be applied to a whole race these days.
The other meaning, of 'untamed', meant 'uncivilized' **in the technical sense**. (Early anthropologists used *savages* for peoples who had not discovered agriculture, and *barbarians* for those who had agriculture but not metalworking).  Like all scientific terms, it should have neither positive nor negative connotations; but the implications of unspoiled innocence (for Huxley in *Brave New World* and Rousseau as previously mentioned, for example) or animal brutishness (in too many examples to name) make it too difficult to use objectively.

Answer (score 1):

What about Rousseau's Noble Savage?

Comment: "Noble Savage" is a good example of so-called positive racism.

Comment: Yeah, think of Montaigne's *Of Cannibals.* By examining a "savage" tribe in Brazil, he offers a critique of Western civilization. Though, I wouldn't call Rousseau's "noble savage" or Montaigne's "Cannibals" examples of "so-called positive racism." --To do so misses their points. "So-called positive racism" might be better attributed to Hegel (in his *Philosophy of History*).